# API problem regarding to Word Replacement

Tags: api, php

I want to replace a word. I was trying to insert using API3 but it is not working properly.

> Word replacement API3

```
$result = civicrm_api3('WordReplacement', 'create', [
  'find_word' => "Contacts",
  'replace_word' => "Data",
  'id' => 1,
]);
```

> Output
>       {

```
"is_error": 0,
"version": 3,
"count": 1,
"id": 1,
"values": {
    "1": {
        "id": "1",
        "find_word": "Contacts",
        "replace_word": "Data",
        "is_active": "",
        "match_type": "",
        "domain_id": "1"
    }
}
```

---

But the values are not stored in 'civicrm_word_replacement' table.
Please give some suggestion.
When I am trying to insert a value using custom php script then it is showing me a following error.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function _drupal_flush_css_js() in C:\xampp\htdocs\copy\sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Utils\System\DrupalBase.php:300
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code includes `'id' => 1`

`create` with an id is for updating an existing value.  Do you already have a WordReplacement with id=1 ?

If you are wanting to create a new one rather than update, just omit `'id' => 1`

Comment: But I want to edit a values of id 1.

Comment: Ok, that's not how I interpreted your question.  What output do you get from `cv api WordReplacement.get` ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are creating it disabled?

> ```
>     "is_active": "",
> ```